# In angular require a field only if it's not disabled

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, input

How can I require a field only if it's not disabled? This didn't work:

```
<form name="foo">
  <input type="text" name="bar" ng-required="!foo.bar.disabled">
</form>
```

Note that I am disabling the field directly through pure javascript, not with `ng-disabled`. I have a `directive` that runs through the form enabling/disabling things.

The directive listens to `$on` messages, and depending on what is gets will run:

```
element.find(':input').prop('disabled', true);
```

The `$on` messages come from a different scope, so I can't directly reference it and do `ng-disabled=....`.

Comment: Provide demo that reproduces problem. We have no idea what your service code does...or why you would need to interact with dom from service and not by model data driving the view

Comment: can you please add service code?

Comment: have you checked the foo.bar.disabled to see the value of that during the code execution??

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, I meant a directive. It does (after various things including listening to `$on` messages) `element.find(':input').prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-disabled` with a scope variable. Your directive can then enable/disable the input through this scope variable. If your directive inherits from another scope, please use an intermediate factory to manage the scope variable.

```
$scope.barDisabled = dataSharer.barDisabled;
```

In above example the `dataSharer` is a factory and `barDisabled` directs to singleton.

In your form:

```
<form name="foo">
  <input type="text" name="bar" ng-required="!bartDisabled" ng-disabled="barDisabled">
</form>
```

Comment: This worked but caused me much grief because each input line had different requirements for when to show or hide, but there was just the single scope variable. I did get it to work though. Is there really no other way?

Comment: @Ariel Yes. Have `inputReq` object in your scope. This object should have many fields `inputReq.foo`, `inputReq.bar` etc. Each these fields have disabled semi fields too. Now you can use this object to map the requirements of many input fields. `<input type="text" name="bar" ng-required="!inputReq.bar.disabled" ng-disabled="inputReq.bar.disabled">`   Please let me know if there is anything.